# to_datetime not working on a string in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date in the format 2014-01-31 05:47.

When its read into pandas the object gets changed as object.

When i try to change it to pd.to_datetime, there is no error, but the datatype does not change to datatime.

Please suggest some way out.

```
T=pd.read_csv("TESTING.csv") 
T['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(T['DATE']) 
T.dtypes 
>DATE object 
T['DATE'] 
>2014-01-31 05:47
```

Comment: How are you reading it into Pandas? Can you show some example code?

Comment: i have csv file which acts as the source. I'm using the read.csv command in pandas module to read it.                  T=pd.read_csv("TESTING.csv")               T['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(T['DATE'])                           T.dtypes                                                         DATE        object                                           T['DATE']         2014-01-31 05:47

Comment: In the excel file the value looks like 1/31/2014  5:47:00 AM                 In case this error message  helps u out              C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.pyc in __new__(cls, data, freq, start, end, periods, copy, name, tz, verify_integrity, normalize, closed, **kwds)
    261             if not np.issubdtype(subarr.dtype, np.datetime64):
    262                 raise ValueError('Unable to convert %s to datetime dtype'
--> % str(data))
    if isinstance(subarr, DatetimeIndex):

ValueError: Unable to convert 0     2014-01-31 05:47

Comment: Can you edit the original question by placing your code examples in it and format it correctly? Difficult to read and understand in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Pandas doesn't understand what the string "2014-01-31 05:47" is other than the fact that you gave it a string. If you read this string in from a CSV file then read the Pandas docs on the read_csv method that allows you to parse datetimes.

However, given something like this:

```
records = ["2014-01-31 05:47", "2014-01-31 14:12"]
df = pandas.DataFrame(records)
df.dtypes
>0    object
>dtype: object
```

This is because you haven't told Pandas how to parse your string into a datetime (or TimeStamp) type.

Using the pandas.to_datetime method is what you want but you must be careful to pass it only the column that has the values you want to convert. Remember that pandas won't mutate the dataframe you're working on, you need to save it again.

```
df[0] = pandas.to_datetime(df[0])
df.dtypes
>0    datetime64[ns]
>dtype: object
```

This is what you want. The cells are now the right format.
There are many ways to achieve the same thing, you could use the apply() method with a lambda, correctly parse from CSV or SQL or work with Series.

Comment: At the datasource, i have added a code to change the date format into YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and the secods are added as 00.                  With this change now , pandas is able to properly convert to the datetime data type.                                                      Thanks for your help Will.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using pandas 0.12 and it converted fine.